# Text split after a specified length but dont break words using grails

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I have a long string that I need to parse into an array of strings that do not exceed 50 characters in length. The tricky part of this for me is making sure that the regex finds the last whitespace before 50 characters to make a clean break between strings since I don't want words cut off.

```
public List<String> splitInfoText(String msg) { 
     int MAX_WIDTH = 50; 
     def line = [] String[] words; 
     msg = msg.trim(); 
     words = msg.split(" "); 
     StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer(); 
     words.each {
        word -> s.append(word + " "); 
        if (s.length() > MAX_WIDTH) { 
          s.replace(s.length() - word.length()-1, s.length(), " "); 
          line << s.toString().trim();
          s = new StringBuffer(word + " "); 
        } 
     } 
     if (s.length() > 0) 
        line << s.toString().trim();
     return line; 
}
```

Comment: Provide your Input and expected output?

Comment: public List<String> splitInfoText(String msg) {

  int MAX_WIDTH = 50;
  
  def line = []
  
  String[] words;
 
  msg = msg.trim();
  
  words = msg.split(" ");
  
  StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
  
  words.each { word ->
  
   s.append(word + " ");
   
   if (s.length() > MAX_WIDTH) {
   
    s.replace(s.length() - word.length()-1, s.length(), " ");
    
    line << s.toString().trim()
    
    s = new StringBuffer(word + " ");
    
   }
   
  }
  
  if (s.length() > 0)
  
   line << s.toString().trim()
   
  return line;
  
 }

Comment: @Nimmy: I attempted to put your code into the main body of the question, but it will look much better if you yourself edit your question and put in your code.

Comment: It will be better if you provide your Input and expected output rather than Groovy code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(".{1,50}(?:\\s|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

Comment: @JRSofty: I had forgotten to initialize the `matchList` parameter - does it work now? And if it doesn't, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Now it works. The original captured the white spaces but not the text except for one word. This works as I would expect it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a Groovier version of Tim's answer is:

```
List matchList = ( subjectString =~ /(?s)(.{1,50})(?:\s|$)/ ).collect { it[ 1 ] }
```

Comment: I don't know Groovy at all, but this does look very groovy to me. +1 :)