# Splitting string without breaking words or ignoring any characters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a single string in multiple lines using regex. Eg.

```
(856587-A) 1806, LEBUH abcdef wref MUTIARA 14000 xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx, xxx.*
```

1. I want to split 32 characters in each line.
2. not remove any special character from the string.
3. if the last word is getting cut, move it to next line.

I was able to achieve the below result by using the adjoining code.

- 856587-A) 1806, LEBUH abcdef wr
- ef MUTIARA 14000 xxxx xxxxx xxx
- xxx, xxx.*

However, it is removing the '(' from the first line breaking the last word and moving it to next line.

```
String nfAddr = "(856587-A) 1806, LEBUH abcdef wref MUTIARA 14000 xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx, xxx.*";

Pattern pn = Pattern.compile("\\w.{1," + (30) + "}");
Matcher mn = pn.matcher(nfAddr);
while (mn.find()) {
                nfAddr = nfAddr + (mn.group()+"\n");
            }
```

Comment: Try `nfAddr = nfAddr.replaceAll(".{30,}?\\b[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\h]*", "$0\n");`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/huRRR8/1). Also, `".{0,30}\\b[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\h]*"` might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Text split after a specified length but dont break words using grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9661823/text-split-after-a-specified-length-but-dont-break-words-using-grails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by breaking the input string into "words".  This could be easy or hard depending on how you define a "word".  For words simply separated by any amount of white space, something like this will do the job nicely:

```
 String[] words = nfAddr.split("\\s+");
```

Now that you've got the individual words, reassemble them into lines of the desired maximum length, adding spaces between them, and then string the resulting lines together with line breaks between them.  Here's an example of a simple routine to do this:

```
static public String formatParagraph(String text, int maxWidth)
{
    String[] words = text.split("\\s+");

    StringBuilder pp = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (String w : words) {
        if (line.length() + w.length() + 1 > maxWidth) {
            if (pp.length() > 0) {
                pp.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            pp.append(line.toString());
            line.setLength(0);
        }
        if (line.length() > 0) {
            line.append(' ');
        }
        line.append(w);
    }
    if (line.length() > 0) {
        if (pp.length() > 0)
            pp.append(System.lineSeparator());
        pp.append(line);
    }
    return pp.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working wonderfully for me instead of regex :)